# Select data basing on multiple (complex) conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this kind of data structure on my server:

Files Table:

```
+----------+--------+------------+
| SystemId | FileId | FileTypeId |
+----------+--------+------------+
|        1 |    100 |          2 |
|        2 |    101 |          1 |
|        2 |    102 |          2 |
|        2 |    103 |          3 |
|        3 |    104 |          1 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

File History Table:

```
+--------+------------+------------------+
| FileId | FileStatus | StatusChangeDate |
+--------+------------+------------------+
|    101 | Done       | 29.01.2021       |
|    101 | Reverted   | 06.01.2021       |
|    101 | Done       | 05.01.2021       |
|    101 | InProgress | 04.01.2021       |
|    101 | New        | 04.01.2021       |
|    102 | Done       | 20.05.2020       |
|    102 | InProgress | 20.05.2020       |
|    102 | New        | 19.05.2019       |
|    103 | New        | 15.04.2019       |
+--------+------------+------------------+
```

Linked Files Table

```
+--------+----------------+------------------+
| FileId | LinkedFileName |    LinkToFile    |
+--------+----------------+------------------+
|    101 | LinkedFile1    | www.file.com/123 |
|    101 | LinkedFile2    | www.file.com/124 |
|    101 | LinkedFile3    | www.file.com/125 |
|    104 | LinkedFile4    | www.file.com/126 |
+--------+----------------+------------------+
```

What I need to extract, are SystemId along with LinkedFileName and LinkToFile for which exists such a SystemId, that contains one or more files with FileTypeId = 1 and also one or more files with FileTypeId = 2, that are both in status "Done" and any one of those files has StatusChangeDate within the previous week. I came up with something like this, but it's not fully what I need and it's super slow.

```
SELECT s.SystemId, s.SystemName, files.FileId, linkedfiles.LinkedFileName, linkedfiles.LinkToFile
FROM SystemsTable s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT f.FileId as FileId
    FROM FilesTable f
    WHERE s.SystemId = f.SystemId
    AND f.FileTypeId = 1
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 fh.*
        FROM FileHistoryTable fh
        WHERE fh.FileId = f.FileId
        AND fh.FileStatus = 'Done' 
        AND fh.StatusChangeDate  >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 0) 
        AND fh.StatusChangeDate  <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 6)
        ORDER BY fh.StatusChangeDate  DESC 
        )
    ) files
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT lf.LinkedFileName as LinkedFileName, lf.LinkToFile as LinkToFile
    FROM LinkedFiles lf
    WHERE lf.FileId = files.FileId
) linkedfiles
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT f.FileId as FileId
    FROM FilesTable f
    WHERE s.SystemId = f.SystemId
    AND f.FileTypeId = 2
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 fh.*
        FROM FileHistoryTable fh
        WHERE fh.FileId = f.FileId
        AND fh.FileStatus = 'Done' 
        AND fh.StatusChangeDate  >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 0) 
        AND fh.StatusChangeDate  <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 6)
        ORDER BY fh.StatusChangeDate  DESC 
        )
)
```

Additional comments:

- Only FileTypeId = 1 can contain linked files
- The expected result for the above tables would be:

```
+----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------------+
| SystemId | SystemName | FileId | LinkedFileName |    LinkToFile    |
+----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------------+
|        2 | System2    |    101 | LinkedFile1    | www.file.com/123 |
|        2 | System2    |    101 | LinkedFile2    | www.file.com/124 |
|        2 | System2    |    101 | LinkedFile3    | www.file.com/125 |
+----------+------------+--------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: @RyanWilson please see the additional comments

Comment: Since this seems partially like a performance issue, please share with us the approx rowcount in each of the tables, and their relevant indexes.  Also SystemsTable was not shared.

Comment: So you are checking for `Done` in the most recent status, which has to be within the dates? Or these are separate: any `Done` and any status within the dates?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should works for you:

```
SELECT s.SystemId, s.SystemName, f.FileId, lf.LinkedFileName, lf.LinkToFile
FROM SystemsTable s
INNER JOIN FilesTable f ON s.SystemId = f.SystemId
INNER JOIN FileHistoryTable fh ON f.FileId = fh.FileId
INNER JOIN LinkedFiles lf ON f.FileId = lf.FileId
WHERE f.FileTypeId  IN (1,2)
AND fh.FileStatus = 'Done'
AND DATEDIFF(wk,fh.StatusChangeDate,GETDATE())<=1
```

Comment: How does this satisfy " that contains one or more files with FileTypeId = 1 and also one or more files with FileTypeId = 2,"  ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query that at least returns what you need.

About performance.
The most heavy part is to get the last version of the file. For this you need to order `FileHistory` rows by `StatusChangeDate` and by some other criteria to deal with ties. Or use `datetime` column instead. So you can use `row_number()` function or use `apply` with index lookup via `select top 1 ... order by StatusChangeDate desc` depending on how much files of type 1 and 2 is there. If it is about 80%, then `row_number` looks preferrable way. Or if you have a single writer of this data, you can manage some `last_version` flag on insert (for single writer there should not be concurrency issues to find the current last version) and index on it to get rid of this computation.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=5604d2b231236a2502a6c560aad29a35)*.

```
  select systemid
  from file_ as f
    cross apply (
      /*The last state*/
      select top 1 *
      from filehistory as fh
      where fh.fileid = f.fileid
      order by
        StatusChangeDate desc
        /*In case there was multiple changes in the same day
          you need to use datetime column type and index on (fileid, StatusChangeDate desc).
          
          Or define the priority of statuses as computed column, index this column also
          and order by it in the same direction as in index
        */
        /*case
          when filestatus = 'Done'
          then 1
          else 0
        end desc*/
    ) as cfv
  where 1 = 1
    /*It is Done at the end*/
    and cfv.filestatus = 'Done'
    and f.filetypeid in (1, 2)
  group by systemid
  /*Where there's at least one file of type 1 and at least one of type 2*/
  having sum(case f.filetypeid when 1 then 1 end) >= 1
    and sum(case f.filetypeid when 2 then 1 end) >= 1
    /*And the change was within previous week*/
    and sum(case
      when StatusChangeDate
          between DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())-1) - 7, getdate())
          and DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate())
      then 1
      end
    ) >= 1
)
select
  f.systemid,
  f.fileid,
  lf.linkedfilename,
  lf.LinkToFile
from file_ as f
  join selected_systems as ss
    on f.systemid = ss.systemid
  join linkedfile as lf
    on f.fileid = lf.fileid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
with
id_cte(SystemId, FileId, FileTypeId) as (
    select f.*
    from FilesTable f
         cross apply (select top(1) FileStatus 
                      from FileHistoryTable fh
                      where fh.FileId = f.FileId
                            and fh.StatusChangeDate  >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 0) 
                            and fh.StatusChangeDate  <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, GETDATE()), 6)
                      order by fh.StatusChangeDate  desc) fs
    where f.FileTypeId in(1, 2)
          and fs.FileStatus='Done')
SELECT f.SystemId, f.FileId, lf.LinkedFileName, lf.LinkToFile
FROM id_cte sc
      join FilesTable f on sc.SystemId=f.SystemId
                           and sc.FileId=f.FileId
     join LinkedFiles lf on f.FileId=lf.FileId;
```

```
SystemId    FileId  LinkedFileName  LinkToFile
2           101     LinkedFile1     www.file.com/123
2           101     LinkedFile2     www.file.com/124
2           101     LinkedFile3     www.file.com/125
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=60a77bb6d417ecc2696ea2df46845a33)

Comment: What happens when FileHistory has another row added, say 100 | Done | 30.01.2021 which would satisfy for SystemId-1  Type=2 being present, but cause Type=1 to be absent. Would the above sql run correctly and reject SystemId=1?

Comment: @donPablo why don't you run it yourself and find out?